# SQL and C# Encryption

Tags: c#, sql, md5

I am using an encryption in C# like this:

```
// Step 1. We hash the passphrase using MD5
// We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
// which is a valid length for the TripleDES encoder we use below  
var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
var hashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
var tdesKey = hashProvider.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(passwordPhrase));

// Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
var tdesAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
                        {
                            Key = tdesKey,
                            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
                        };

// Step 3. Attempt to encrypt the string
var dataToEncrypt = utf8.GetBytes(message);
var encryptor = tdesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();

return Convert.ToBase64String(
    encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(
        dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length));
```

I want to use the same process in SQL Server. So I mean that an encrypted message from C# code and encrypted message from SQL Server must be the same string.

For example, `683846` will become `fN8r09iDu4c=` in SQL Server too.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx should get you going for the md5 part and then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx for triple DES encryption.  Literally the first google hits for "ms sql md5" and "ms sql triple des"

Comment: MD5 is (non-reversible) **hashing** - not **encryption** (which would be reversible)

Answer (score 1):

You can only achieve this if you use the same C# code in the server too, via SQLCLR. The native SQL encryption functions do **not** create same output as your C# code (even when same key and initialization vector is used). Native SQL encryption can only be decrypted by SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) for Triple DES encryption and [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) to derive key material from passphrase.

You would have to store passphrase in SQL Server somewhere and I am not sure what is the best way to do that. Alternatively you can accept passphrase as a parameter passed in from the user.